# How to mock angular ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, rxjs, router

I have this code of `ActivatedRoute` with `map` followed by `subscribe`.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private actr: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.actr.data.map(data => data.aList).subscribe((res) => {
        console.log('res ------------------------- ', res); // It is not showing this.
        this.myResponse = res;
    });
}

   ngOnInit() {
      // some code
      // myResponse is undefined
   }

}
```

I have tried in the spec file :

```
class MockActivatedRouter {

    public map = (data) => data.aList = of({some: [] });
    // Or 
    public map = (data) => of({some: [] });
 }
```

None of them works.

Comment: what is `map(data => data.aList)`? Is that a method on `Observable` of rxjs@5? Or this method is created in the router config / resolver? How do you provide your mock? Please post the whole spec file

Comment: please use the angular tag for the new angular 2+ as angularjs tag is for angular 1.x

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to mock it like this:

```
class MockActivatedRouter {
  data = of({some: [] }); // Dont remember the old rxjs5 syntax but you might want to use Observable.of(...)
}
```

Means `ActivatedRoute` has a property `data` which is observable you subscribe to in your constructor.

I usually mock it just with plain object and provide observable as a `Subject` to be able to emit anytime I want in the test.

And I supposed you know how to provide your mock in the test:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  providers: [{
    provide: ActivatedRoute,
    useClass: MockActivatedRouter
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out we can just simply do :

```
class MockActivatedRouter {
  public map = (data) => of(MyResponse.data.aList);
}

class MyResponse {
  static data = {
     // data 
  }
}
```

Comment: that's not really good idea because when someone comes and maybe changes implementation little bit (like placing another operator before `map`) the test will start to fail.